# Docker not running .exe file

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, docker

I have a question regarding dockerizing C/C++ project. I am using visual studio compiler image because I have a lot of environment trouble with running MinGW compiler.

I confirmed project using visual studio compiler image and building solution perfectly, but I'm seeing problem with actually running generated .exe file in docker container environment.

Following is my dockerfile code :

```
# escape=`

# Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE.txt in the project root for license information.

ARG FROM_IMAGE=microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5-sdk-windowsservercore-1709
FROM ${FROM_IMAGE}

# Reset the shell.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Set up environment to collect install errors.
COPY Install.cmd C:\TEMP\
ADD https://aka.ms/vscollect.exe C:\TEMP\collect.exe

# Install Node.js LTS
ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-x64.msi C:\TEMP\node-install.msi
RUN start /wait msiexec.exe /i C:\TEMP\node-install.msi /l*vx "%TEMP%\MSI-node-install.log" /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL

# Download channel for fixed install.
ARG CHANNEL_URL=https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel
ADD ${CHANNEL_URL} C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman

# Download and install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 for native desktop workload.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
RUN C:\TEMP\Install.cmd C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended`
    --installPath C:\BuildTools

# Execute commands once container runs
# Build solution using MSVC
ENTRYPOINT C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat &&
```

I copied it from microsoft official website here : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-msvc-in-a-docker-container-for-your-c-projects/

and following is my output

```
C:\Users\cshim31\smarts-pxie-executive>docker run -v C:\Users\cshim31\smarts-pxie-executive:c:\smarts-pxie-executive -it buildtools2017native:2017 msbuild C:\smarts-pxie-executive\Project4.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 3/10/2021 6:07:46 PM.
Project "C:\smarts-pxie-executive\Project4.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|x64".
Project "C:\smarts-pxie-executive\Project4.sln" (1) is building "C:\smarts-pxie-executive\Project4.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Debug\Project4.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
Link:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  Project4.vcxproj -> C:\smarts-pxie-executive\x64\Debug\Project4.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Debug\Project4.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Debug\Project4.tlog\Project4.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\smarts-pxie-executive\Project4.vcxproj" (default targets).

Done Building Project "C:\smarts-pxie-executive\Project4.sln" (default targets).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.12

C:\Users\cshim31\smarts-pxie-executive>
```

After building, it instantly terminated without printing out program output.
Instead, I tried going into docker environment and running .exe by myself.

and following is output :

```
C:\smarts-pxie-executive\x64\Debug>Project4.exe

C:\smarts-pxie-executive\x64\Debug>
```

it didn't print out error messages. It works perfectly fine when I opened .exe file on local computer. I am not sure how I should resolve problem since there isn't error message that I can see and fix.

Comment: Sometimes it's an issue with missing windows dependencies in the servercore image. Can usually get around it by copying over the dependencies (if you know which) or by using the full windows image.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? I don't understand what you meant by missing windows dependencies. Do you mean servercore libraries missing?

Comment: Windows dlls, such as under C:\Windows\System32. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images) at differences between base images.

Comment: @LukeShim **Where you able to figure why after running .exe nothing happened?** I am seeing same issue. So far we figured out windows update is causing this to break. we uninstalled and .exe started working. Uninstalling updates were temporary solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with a Rust executable on a Docker image based on `windows/servercore:ltsc2019`. I used [Dependency Walker](https://dependencywalker.com/) to open the executable and saw that it depended on `vcruntime140.dll`. Then after downloading and installing the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package within the Docker container, my executable ran correctly.